# How to Make array_diff ignore One Value in PHP

Tags: php

If you do an array_diff between two values:

```
$ignore = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
```

How can you make it avoid removing one specific value from `$arr1?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two arrays for example.

```
$arr = ['something', 'another thing', 'three things'];
$arr = ['something', 'another thing', 'different thing'];
```

And the value you want to keep:

```
$keep = 'something';
```

If you need that certain value to *always* be there, it probably would be easiest to just explicitly add it after doing the diff.

```
$ignore = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
$ignore[] = $keep;
```

but if you only need it to *not be removed* if it is present, then you can use `array_udiff`.

```
$ignore = array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, function($a, $b) use ($keep) {
    if ($a == $keep) return -1;
    return $a == $b ? 0 : 1;
});
```